# Page is not taking full size of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a dashboard page for posting articles for my website.
i have a sidebar and a section where my posting page will appear but that page is not taking up the full size of section...
here is the screenshot of my problem https://ibb.co/kuZBQm

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class=" container">
  <aside>
    <a href="#" onclick="load_topgamespost()"><button> Top Games</button></a>
  </aside>

  <section id="section"></section>
</div>


<script>
  function load_topgamespost() {
    document.getElementById("section").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="/topgames/topgamespost"></object>';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the width specified?

Comment: i have added in my post

Answer (score 0):

So your `section` is the correct size, the problem is with the `object` element inside it.

Use

```
section object{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: height is increased to full size but width is still same

Comment: @Zayn if you copy pasted my code, i had misspelled the word `width`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it :)

Comment: @Zayn as i mentioned in the answer, the `section` element is correct. But you have no style set for the `object` element that you inject through javascript. So it uses its default values which is what you were seeing.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
height: 100vh;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

try this style in your body tag i think this suits in your problem